# Self closing span inside label

Tags: pug

I am trying to get a self-closing span inside a label in Jade. This is the code I am using:

```
label
  span/
  | Remember Me
```

This provides the output:

```
<label><span>Remember Me</span></label>
```

However, I am expecting (and when putting this in one of the code boxes in the docs, it works):

```
<label><span/>Remember Me</label>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Works for me. [`span/` produces `<span/>`](http://i.imgur.com/Thow5fM.png)

Comment: I have the same problem, apparently either browsers will not properly handle a self-closing span, or there is something else that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I am just putting the HTML inside manually. Turns out you can't have a self closing `span`.

Jade code:

```
<label><span></span>Remember Me</label>
```

Comment: That's the workaround, but I really would like to understand why browsers work that way.